# disable hyperlink upon click in css

Tags: html, css, joomla, menu

I have a menu constructed of divs. For this I am using the default Joomla menu, modified to my own taste. This is a html question though, so that's why I'm posting it here.

The class of the top menu item that has a sub-menu underneath it is called "deeper parent". When this is clicked, instead of going to the link it has, I want it to just open the sub-menu, that's it.

I tried

```
.deeper {
pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}

.parent {
pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

This however, disables the display of the sub-menu as well, which did show up before I used this css code.

Does anyone know how I can make the sub-menu appear upon hover, as well as upon click (for tables ;) ), without referring to the link that's behidn the top menu item?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable click events using CSS. This must be done using Javascript/jQuery.

Assuming you're using jQuery on your site which most Joomla site do, you can use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#element').on('click', function(){ 
      e.preventDefault();

      // Rest of code to show the menu  
   });

});
```

You could also set the **type** for the parent menu item to **separator** in the Joomla Menu Manager which wraps the menu item in `<span>` tags rather than `<a>`